# How to move a recurring event to an other calendar in Python using Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, events, google-calendar-api, recurring

I'm not able with the use of the function `.move()` in Google Calendar API to move an instance of a recurring event to an other calendar...
Any Idea ?

My code :

```py
def eventmover(calendarId, eventId, destination, login):
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=login)        
    service.events().instances().move(calendarId=calendarId,eventId=eventId, destination=destination).execute()
```

Returned error:

> json returned "Cannot change the organizer of an instance.">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the `move` on the [instance](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) of the event, not on the [event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move) itself. They are both methods of the Event class, you can't use them together. You should do:

```
def eventmover(calendarId, eventId, destination, login):
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=login)        
    service.events().move(calendarId=calendarId,eventId=eventId, destination=destination).execute()
```

Comment: `json returned "Cannot change the organizer of an instance.">`
Thks for the quick respond but it's not possible i think...

Comment: That's odd, I tested it and it worked. Try with another language like Apps Script.

Comment: In my case I used the field `recurringEventId` as I had to move an event series.